# Como criar um botão dentro de um iframe para o fechar

Tags: html, iframe

Precisava de criar um botão dentro de um `iframe` em um canto para o fechar. Tenho uma galeria de imagens e ao clicar em uma imagem vai abrir um `iframe`, o seguinte código já faz isso.

Mas agora precisava de criar um botão em um canto dentro do `iframe` (preferência no canto superior direito) ao ser pressionado o botão teria de fechar o `iframe`. Atenção as páginas que vou abrir pelo `iframe` não tenho acesso ao código. E Após fechar o `iframe` através do botão deve ser possível voltar a abrir o mesmo clicando na galeria de imagens.

Alguma ideia de como eu o possa fazer?

Tenho o seguinte código já feito:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="iframe1" href="https://www.google.pt">
    <img src="images\pt.png" alt="PT" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Google PT</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="iframe1" href="https://www.google.co.uk/">
    <img src="images\en.png" alt="EN" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Google EN</div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <iframe name='iframe1' id='link' width="800" height='500' style="border:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a página que vou mostar no iframe não tenho acesso a ela, logo preciso eu proprio de o criar

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a outra pergunta e bem parecida mas não me consegue ajudar

Comment: Entendi. Achei que as páginas que estavam na pergunta eram apenas exemplos. Irei remover esses comentários e o voto para fechar. Aliás, por quê o botão precisa estar no iframe e não na sua própria página?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na realidade não vou usar essas páginas, não deixam de ser exemplo.. contudo as páginas que vou usar não tenho acesso a elas a mesma...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a função do botão será apenas ocultar o iframe, não vejo porquê você inserí-lo dentro do mesmo; você pode criar o botão na sua página e apenas posicioná-lo sobre o iframe, na posição desejada. Veja um exemplo:

```css
.iframe {
  position: relative;
}

.iframe button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe">
  <iframe src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/hitchhikers/images/2/2f/The-Hitchhikers-Guide-to-the-Galaxy-586-5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110623191658" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="480"></iframe> 
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">X</button>
</div>
```

Perceba que o `button` está definido na sua própria página, não necessitando de definí-lo dentro do iframe.

Comment: Percebi perfeitamente o código está em falta apenas uma coisa que esqueci de mencionar na pergunta, vou já acrescentar. Abri o iframe bem, consegui fechar com o botão também, mas eu pretendo voltar a abrir o iframe quando voltar a clicar em uma imagem da galeria. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: A lógica é exatamente a mesma. O que tentou fazer?

Comment: Sim, já consegui mas tive de usar JS, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Este código é preciso usar jquery.

Se o iframe não pode deixar de existir, então na pagina que você chama no iframe faça o botão e coloque o id do elemento que você quer remover desta forma:

```
$(function(){
     $("#id_do_botao_fechar").click(function() {
          $("#id_elemento").remove();
     });
});
```

Mas se de fato você quer remover o iframe:

```
$(function(){
     $("#id_do_botao_fechar_fora_do_iframe").click(function() {
          $("#nav").empty();
     });
});
```

Assim ele vai remover tudo que esta dentro da tag com id "nav".

Comment: como crio o botão?

Comment: Pode clicar uma div ou img o importante é só colocar o id no elemento ex: <div id="id_do_botao_fechar">Fechar</div> ou <a href="#" id="id_do_botao_fechar">Fechar</a>

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda e resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui chegar a este resultado:

```js
function closeiframe() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none";
}

function openiframe() {
 document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "inherit";
}
```

```css
.iframe {
  osition: relative;
}

.iframe button {
  position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="iframe1" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Página_principal" onclick="openiframe()">
    <img src="images\test1.png" alt="test1" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">test1</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="iframe1" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Boas-vindas" onclick="openiframe()">
    <img src="images\test2.png" alt="test2" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">test2</div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
 <iframe name='iframe1' id='link' width="800" height='500' style="border:none;"></iframe>
 <button onclick="closeiframe()">X</button>
</div>
```